# Triggering dynamic web search box with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write JavaScript code in `Tampermonkey` that will simulate entering search text into a dynamic (search results triggered and updated with each letter typed) web site search box. The HTML for the search element is as follows:

```
<input class="Fz-s Pstart-30 Py-10 Fw-200 W-100 Bxsh-n" id="playerSearch" placeholder="Search Players" autocomplete="off" type="search" value="" data-reactid=".1l1mm91hvr4.1.1.0.2.0.0.$primary-1-DesktopLineupSelection.0.0.0.$=10:0.1.0.0.2">
```

The web site's JavaScript (if it helps) for the page element is:

```
a.createElement(E,{className:"Fz-s Pstart-30 Py-10 Fw-200 W-100 Bxsh-n",id:"playerSearch",type:"search",placeholder:"Search Players",autoComplete:"off",onClick:this.handleSearchClick,valueLink:{value:m._search,requestChange:this.searchFilterChange}})
```

My JavaScript code in `Tampermonkey` inputs a text value into the search box with:

```
$('#playerSearch').val(fullname);
```

Unfortunately, that does not trigger the dynamic search results. Thinking maybe I had to click the control before entering the value, I tried the following, with no luck:

```
$('#playerSearch').click();
$('#playerSearch').val(fullname);
$('#playerSearch').change();
```

I have also tried the following with no luck:

```
$('#playerSearch').val(fullname);
$('#playerSearch').trigger("input");
```

I'm kind of a newb at this stuff, but feel like I have to be pretty close. If any of you brainiacs out there can help me, I'd be really really thankful.

Comment: if possible provide a fiddle and be more clear (i mean what you want to trigger, just an input box or the results if results, how you are getting results)

Comment: Here is a `Fiddle` of the page in question. [https://jsfiddle.net/cgnmof8e/embedded/result/] Note that I didn't need to enter any JavaScript into the Fiddle to make the dynamic text search work. Maybe this is simpler than I thought.

Comment: Just to be more clear, my Tampermonkey script is currently entering the right value into the search box for the players, but the dynamic search isn't triggered. The results are unchanged. I'm trying to find the right code to make the search results change.

Comment: Also, for some reason the jsfiddle link isn't working right. It works fine if you copy->paste it instead of clicking it.